# Where is the optimal location to store a custom language configuration file (config.xml) for Syncfusion's Winforms EditControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

Sorry if this question is too rudimentary. I am very new to C# and still learning best practices.

I am following instructions [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/syntax-editor/syntax-highlighting#apply-custom-configuration-in-editcontrol) to create a custom syntax highlighting scheme for use in their EditControl component.

They recommend loading the config using the following:

```
private string configFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\..\..\config.xml";

this.editControl1.Configurator.Open(configFile);
```

This ends up evaluating to `SolutionName\SolutionName\bin\Config.xml`

This doesn't seem right to me.

My question is simply: Should I just drop my `config.xml` file into the `bin` folder like the article seemingly recommends, or should I place it somewhere else?

The reason I'm asking this is because there are debug folders in the bin folder, and I don't think this is the proper way to store my configuration. Will this path still work when I compile and redistribute my application?

Should I add the config file some other way?

To any seasoned C# developers: How and where would you store this configuration file?

I appreciate any help regarding this simple question.

Comment: Well, the normal application config (ExeName.exe.config) is usually stored along with the executable, so that seems like a good bet, but this is just an opinion.

Comment: This is an opinion based question, it depends on what you want or like. I use resource or sqlite database. There are so many answers as users

Comment: Got it. I apologize if this is too open-ended. I will delete it if necessary. I just wanted to make sure that everything will still work after I finish the application and redistribute.

Comment: If you store it in the same location as the exe, then if there are multiple users, if one user changes it, then it will affect other users. If you want users to be able to change it independently, then it would make more sense to use the Roaming folder, e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<CompanyName>\<ProductName>\\`` which is referenced by the code `String folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`

Comment: I don't want users to be able to change it at all. It's a theme for a text editor that's built in to the application that I don't want the end user to mess with. So would adding it as a resource accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the custom language configuration file(config.xml) in your project folder itself, where other resources files are located.

Comment: Would this allow end-users to modify the file after install? I don't want my users editing the file, I'm just using it because it's the easiest way to configure custom syntax highlighting in an text editor component (from Syncfusion).